# Getting Behind the target

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

This is more of a geometry question but I can't comeup with a proper way to do the following,

- A is my agent
- X is the player

I am trying to calculate a point w1 that I will be using as a way point to get to w2 which is my agents goal.

```
                                                         -|
                                                          |
      w2        X                   A                     |
                                                          |
                                                         -|
                w1
```

I am trying to avoid graph search as I only need a single waypoint around the target and come up with a geometric relation any thoughts? any circle line intersection property that I am missing.

EDIT: constraints for the w1 is that it should be at a distance x and axw1 angle be 90 degrees. both a and x is circular objects.

Comment: What's the constraint here? Can w1 be anywhere? Or anywhere at a right angle from X along A-w2? Or at a certain distance? Your question is ill-defined.

Comment: @Jean my bad added constraints.

Comment: What are the givens? The coordinates of A, X, and w2? Are they always aligned horizontally like that? Why is the shape of A and X relevant? This is like pulling teeth!

Comment: @Jean, I know A my position, X player position and w2 my target w1 is unknown. No they are not always aligned.

Comment: So A, W, and w2 are *not* aligned? Then I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for a geometric relation describing the position of w1. Assuming A, W, and w2 are aligned and w1 is at distance d from X at a right angles from line AX, this is the system of two equations to solve for `w1`:

[image] i.e. segment w1-X is perpendicular to segment X-A

[image] i.e. distance between w1 and X is equal to d.

The above is in vectorial form. The same set of two equations can be expressed in scalar form:

[image]
[image]

Two equations to solve for two unknowns (x_w1 and y_w1) using high school algebra.